# Mod Rewrite With Get

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I've run through the previous attempts here at solving this, but can't seem to figure this out. What I've got is a user page user.php which contains something like user.php?u=Chris

I'm trying to rewrite this as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ user.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

so that it appears as www.mydomain.com/user/chris

Each time I try to get to the page I'm confronted with my own message not logged....which comes from msg=notlogged in the below section. I'm thinkign its an issue with the get variable after the rewrite. Is there any truth to that or am I looking at it the wrong way? How can I maintain the get variable so that u can be checked within my database?

```
<?php
include_once("../includes/check_login_status.php");
// Initialize any variables that the page might echo
$u = "";
$userlevel = "";
$profile_pic = "";
$profile_pic_btn = "";
$avatar_form = "";
$joindate = "";
$lastsession = "";
// Make sure the _GET username is set, and sanitize it
if(isset($_GET["u"])){
$u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
} else {
   header("location: http://www..com");
    exit(); 
}

// Select the member from the users table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
// Now make sure that user exists in the table
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
if($numrows < 0){
header("location: http://www..com/message.php?msg=notlogged");
    exit(); 
}
// Check to see if the viewer is the account owner
$isOwner = "no";
if($u == $log_username && $user_ok == true){
$isOwner = "yes";
$profile_pic_btn = '<a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="toggleElement(\'avatar_form\')">Toggle Avatar Form</a>';
$avatar_form  = '<form id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="php_parsers/photo_system.php">';
$avatar_form .=   '<h4>Change your avatar</h4>';
$avatar_form .=   '<input type="file" name="avatar" required>';
$avatar_form .=   '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>';
$avatar_form .= '</form>';
}
else 
var_dump($_GET);
//header("location: http://www..com/message.php?msg=notlogged");
// Fetch the user row from the query above
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$profile_id = $row["id"];
$userlevel = $row["userlevel"];
$avatar = $row["avatar"];
$signup = $row["signup"];
$email = $row["email"];
$username = $row["username"];
$lastlogin = $row["lastlogin"];
$joindate = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($signup));
$lastsession = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($lastlogin));
}
$profile_pic = '<img src="user/'.$u.'/'.$avatar.'" alt="'.$u.'">';
if($avatar == NULL){
$user1 = "";
$profile_pic = '<img src="images/avatardefault.jpg" alt="'.$user1.'">';
$username ="'.$email.'";
}
?>
<?php 
$coverpic = "";
$sql = "SELECT filename FROM photos WHERE user='$u' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$filename = $row[0];
$coverpic = '<img src="user/'.$u.'/'.$filename.'" height="200" width="200" alt="pic">';
}
?>

<?php
// If the page requestor is not logged in, usher them away
$notification_list = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE username LIKE BINARY '$log_username' ORDER BY date_time DESC";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows < 1){
$notification_list = "You do not have any notifications or you're viewing a fellow traders profile";
} else {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$noteid = $row["id"];
$initiator = $row["initiator"];
$app = $row["app"];
$note = $row["note"];
$date_time = $row["date_time"];
$date_time = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($date_time));
$notification_list .= "<p><a href='user.php?u=$initiator'>$initiator</a> | $app<br />$note</p>";
}
}
mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE transactions SET notescheck=now() WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1");
?>
```

This is all that is within my htaccess rewrites. I have this michael.

```
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ user.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: `$numrows` should _never_ be less than zero. Even if it was `false` or `null`, that would still be _equal_ to zero in loose comparison. Is that the only code path that results in the `notlogged` message? And are you certain that the logic which handles `notlogged` in `message.php` is not faulty?

Comment: Basic debugging and error handling is in order. Remove the `header()` redirects temporarily, and inspect the contents of `$numrows`, as well as the contents of `$user_query`. Make sure it returned, and if not, look at `mysqli_error($db_conx)`

Comment: If they aren't in the database they don't have permission to go any further. At this point they are directed to the message page...if they are found then they may continue on..everything was working before I added the rewrite*.

Comment: Did you `var_dump($_GET)` to make sure the value is being passed in? That should be your very first debugging step. Do you have _other_ subsequent rewrite rules which may match this? You don't have a `[L]` flag...

Comment: I also note that your example is `www.mydomain.com/user/chris`, but your RewriteRule expects a trailing slash as in `www.mydomain.com/user/chris/` and won't match without it.

Comment: I've added everything within my htaccess Michael

Comment: This is what I get on var dump     
   

`array(1) { ["u"]=> string(5) "Chris" }`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski After debug I found it is actually lower that it is pushing away, but still same issue.Still an issue with getting the variable after rewrite. The var dump came out fine, but its not pushing after the rewrite.

Comment: What do you mean _lower that it is pushing away_?  If the `var_dump()` shows `u` is populated in the script, then it is your application logic, not the rewrite at fault.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski the header is being triggered lower than I initially thought. As you said u is populated, but I'm not sure what you mean by application logic is at fault? Can you expand on that a bit?

**EDIT** 

I've included the entire script..Is that what  you mean?

Comment: `$log_username` is not set at the time you check `if ($u == $log_username)`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks for being patient with me. I'm not sure what you mean by $log_username is not set at the time checked. I call the log_username when I include check_login_status.php . Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Oh boy I just figured out what you meant and corrected it. I'm not getting any rewrite occuring though. **NOTE**I changed my paths and forgot to change them back on includes.

Comment: Are you using php session ? if not time to start doing so.

Comment: Yes I'm using php session, but this is a special case.